# Wrong disk geometry on USB enclosure

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, raid, sata

I have a sata disk formatted in a NAS that use it in linux raid 1.

I have removed the disk from the NAS ed mounted it internally in a PC with linux.

Linux correctly recognize the disk and I'm able to assemble the raid and mount partitions.

fdisk correctly give me:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fdisk -l  /dev/sde

Disk /dev/sde: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes

255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sde1            2048     4196351     2097152   fd  Linux raid autodetect

/dev/sde2         5244928  1953497087   974126080   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sde3         4196352     5244927      524288   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

The problem is I need to use it inside a USB sata external enclosure. I have installed the same disk on the external enclosure e connect the USB to the linux PC.
But now fdisk report a wrong disk geometry:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fdisk -l  /dev/sde

Disk /dev/sde: 33 MB, 33348608 bytes

2 heads, 32 sectors/track, 1017 cylinders, total 65134 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x00000000

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sde1            2048     4196351     2097152   fd  Linux raid autodetect

/dev/sde2         5244928  1953497087   974126080   fd  Linux raid autodetect

/dev/sde3         4196352     5244927      524288   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

And I'm not able to assembly the raid and mount partitions.

How I can solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a problem with HPA

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area

```
hdparm -N /dev/sdX
```